# Motherboard Running on Li-Po Batteries Rebooting Randomly

Tags: power-supply

I am using a [MSI Z87I AC](http://www.flipkart.com/msi-z87i-acmotherboard/p/itmdvwyuwfda4hpv?pid=MBDDVWYNJG9PFUYX&srno=b_1&ref=f7c84296-0501-4c7d-8bc6-4154ed0886c6) motherboard with an Intel Core i7 4770T (2.5Ghz 8MB 4C 8T) processor, 2GB of DDR3 RAM and a 32GB SSD. This setup is used on my autonomous underwater vehicle. The  power supply unit is a miniature [picoPSU-150](http://www.mini-box.com/picoPSU-150-XT). The board is powered using two 8000 mAh, 30C, Lithium-Polymer batteries in parallel usually charged up to around 11.5V.

The motherboard is randomly rebooting. The motherboard runs Ubuntu 14.04 and has a daemon continuously running on it which uses OpenCV (open source computer vision library) to process underwater feeds from two webcams.

I have observed reboot at different instants -

1) When the daemon starts, or
2) The daemon has started and it access the webcams, or
3) The daemon has been running properly and then some extra activity such as a user SSHing into or executing a different application,or
4) When the Linux kernel starts loading, just after the grub screen

The first time I start the system, say after a couple of days, it works fine for 2 - 3 hours and then reboots. During these hours I switch on and off the daemon a number of times and everything stays fine. Then slowly the reboot frequency keeps on increasing. Finally I end up with the motherboard rebooting continuously every time at point #1 or #4 mentioned above.

There is no overheating problem. Can it be a problem with the PSU? Or can it be a voltage or power problem? The batteries are used in the range 10.5V - 11.5V. The max TDP for the processor is 45W. The PSU is rated for 150W and Li-Po batteries can easily supply the required current.

Comment: Have you monitored the voltage and current usage at these points? I suspect that you're just plain old out of juice.

Comment: Hard to dis-agree with previous comment. Using a 150W supply at <12V draws >12A which is a lot for 2x8Ah batteries. I don't understand why they advertise these as 30C - who wants 240A from 8Ah batteries ? Try the batteries in series if the power supply will allow it.

Comment: Big cap across battery feed at PCB (probably) can't hurt.

Comment: The picoPSU is not designed to take a variable input, it just passes the "12V" line directly through the connector. The ATX voltage tolerance is 5%, so you're out of spec for most of the battery's discharge curve.

Answer (score 2):

A 3 cell Lipo battery should read close to 12.6V at full charge, and at 10.5V is almost completely drained. If your system is lasting 2~3 hours on a charge then the average current drain must be less than 8A (16Ah/2hrs) or 0.5C, so the voltage should be holding above 11.0V throughout the discharge.

If battery voltage is dropping to 10.5V then you are draining it down to the 'knee' of the discharge curve. At this point any increase in current demand will cause the voltage to drop precipitously. The black line on the graph below shows a typical voltage curve at 1C discharge. At 0.5C the line would be slightly higher, but with an even sharper knee at the end.

The initial voltage under load should be above 12V. If it isn't then you should check to make sure that the charger is putting a full charge into the battery. When the battery is taken off the charger the 'resting' or no-load voltage should be just below 12.6V.

I suspect you just need more capacity to get the run time you want. However to make sure you could record the current and voltage with a data logger, and see if the reboots correspond to times of low voltage. By calculating the Ah used you can also determine the required battery capacity (should be at least 20% more than what you expect to use).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Typically, on PC motherboards, the 12V input is not used by logic (whatever kind) directly. There used to be some uses, such as RS232 ports, or possibly an audio amp could run off the 12V line... and also the HW monitor (a part of the SuperIO chip) may have an ADC input for the 12V rail. Other than that, the mighty 12V input rail is nowadays used primarily to feed the primary side of various buck converters: the CPU VRM (step down to around 1.2-ish Volt), another VRM for the RAM (2.5, 1.8, maybe 1.5 V) and several other such low-volt rails, whatever the different chips may need. These buck converters use PWM controllers and FETs that are specced for way over 12 V, maybe 20 to 40 V may be some nominal values. The capacitors typically used at these positions are nowadays 16V solid polymer (used to be 25V "wet" elyt in the past). The buck converters have stabilized output, and actually accept a pretty broad range of input. 10 to 15 V should be technically no problem.

Some motherboards may contain a POST check in the BIOS, which takes a look at the rail voltages (through the HW monitor chip) and may refuse to boot if some voltage (or temperature!) is out of tolerance - but this "feature" is pretty rare.

Apart from 12 V, an ATX PC motherboard typically expects precise (5%) 5V and 3.3V rails at its power input - although especially 5V nowadays is only ever used for interface logic, rather than to actually power some chip cores... 3.3 Volts may actually be used to power some chips (NIC's, SuperIO, BIOS Flash and the like) - but unless you add some hungry PCI card, the consumption is typically pretty small. On a modern Haswell-based board, the 5V and 3.3V rails combined will probably amount to well under 10 W (maybe under 5 W). Disk drives are also in that ballpark (or less).

And this is exactly what the PicoPSU caters for.
It contains some pretty efficient buck converters for the 5V and 3.3V rails.
I've seen the PicoPSU-160-XT and I am amazed - two buck channels with synchronous rectified output, well over 90% of efficiency... 
If you need to feed 10-20 W of output juice, just calculate how much heat the buck switchers dissipate. They hardly warm up.
The "12V straight through" branch is implemented using a P-channel FET with just a few milliohms of RdsON. That won't break a sweat, either. I would be more concerned about the parasitic series resistances in the connectors used (some beefy wiring terminals would appeal more to me, for industrial use).

Back to the point though (after the architectural intro). The PicoPSU(-160-XT) contains a dedicated chip to generate its "power good" output (and one other internal sanity status signal, it would seem). This "power sanity watchdog" chip is called TPS3510, made by TI. It keeps an eye on 3.3V, 5V (both over/under-voltage via a dedicated input pin per rail) and 12V via the VDD input, which also serves to power the chip. The 12V input nominally only checks for over-voltage, but a 12V under-voltage check can also be (and is!) implemented using the PGI pin. The manual for the PicoPSU specifies that the "power good" output of the PSU (motherboard input, via the ATX connector) is active between 10.5 V and 13.5 V. This would explain why the motherboard "resets" itself below approximately 10.5V. Looking into the TPS3510 datasheet, this PicoPSU spec might come with quite some "spread" of tolerance - the upper limit might actually be well over 14 V depending on an external diode, and the lower limit depends on the precision of the external resistive divider (and the TPS3510 chip itself has quite some specced tolerance on both thresholds).

There are two important implications:

1) the Power Good signal might be a clue as to why the motherboard falls into a reset, below or above some voltage thresholds
[edit]: actually the PicoPSU *shuts off output* (including 12V) when it detects under-voltage, and only comes back when the input returns into the permitted range, with a short added delay (around half a second by the looks of it). Observed in a lab. So the motherboard doesn't perform a reset,
it actually performs a proper power cycle.

2) if you know enough of small-signal electronics, and you don't care about PicoPSU warranty, you may try a mod to the external passive network around the TPS3510 (VDD and PGI inputs) to move the limits to where you like them.
It seems to be a matter of one resistor for the lower limit (PGI) and one resistor for the upper limit (the 12V rail applied to VDD via a diode and maybe an additional resistor in series).

Obviously you're cruising well outside of the ATX spec for the 12V power rail. Warranty void, you're on your own. But it might as well just work :-) Elyt's and ceramic caps tend to age faster if you run them close to the nominal voltage, but then again the solid-poly are very nice and the ceramics tend to have the voltage 2x over-estimated by sane mobo designers, so a few Volts above the nominal 12 shouldn't hurt.

The PicoPSU seems to be a pretty decent job, only it could be a little less expensive, given the BOM and complexity, compared to a similarly priced PS/2 PSU or a motherboard :-)